# How can I translate english input field text into hindi and which translator to good to convert it using reactJS

Tags: reactjs

Actually I am just trying to translate one English input field into hindi. I am trying it by using google translator but didn't get the output. so please i need the help to translte language in reactjs. I install the library ie "npm i react-google-translate" I didn't get the the translation code.

Can anyone guide me that how to write code on it?

I am just trying simple translation.